# Inconsistency in misuse of "reverse" in list context

Tags: perl

```
print reverse "word"; # prints 'word'
```

```
print reverse foreach ("word"); # prints nothing (empty string)
```

I am using Perl v5.24.

list context is forced by `print`, and these statements are "bad" 
 because `reverse` should be called in scalar contest to be useful.

Nevertheless, why the inconsistency?

Comment: Re "*why the inconsistency?*", What inconsistency?

Comment: Re "*because reverse should be called in scalar contest to be useful*", nonsense. `say for reverse qw( abc def ghi );`

Answer (score 2):

> print reverse foreach ("word"); # prints nothing (empty string)

What you have written is

```
for ( 'word' ) {
    print reverse();
}
```

That code clearly executes the loop just once with `$_` set to `word`, and prints a reversed empty list

Perhaps you should avoid statement modifiers until you are more familiar with the language

As [**tjd** comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985679/inconsistency-in-misuse-of-reverse-in-list-context/43986286?noredirect=1#comment75001925_43986286), `reverse` will reverse either a list or a string. In list context (as imposed by the call to `print`) it expects a list of parameters to reverse, and ignores `$_`. In scalar context it would just concatenate all parameters passed to it and reverse the resulting string; in the absence of any parameters it will reverse the string in `$_`

Comment: More precisely, while `reverse()` will use `$_` in scalar context, `print` imposes list context.

Answer (score 0):

The [reverse](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) can indeed be used in either scalar context

```
perl -wE'$w = "hello"; $r = reverse $w; say $r'  # olleh
```

or in list context

```
perl -wE'say join " ", reverse qw(hello there)'  # there hello
```

Both are useful and there is no "*inconsistency*" in these behaviors.

One thing to watch out for is that when a list is used in scalar context

```
perl -wE'say scalar reverse qw(hello there)'  # erehtolleh
```

then the list gets concatenated and `reverse` returns a string with characters in reverse order.

---

I am adding another "gotcha" for completeness, even as it has been covered in other answers.

The `reverse` defaults to `$_` in scalar context, as expected. However, in list context it just doesn't take `$_`, and in `for (@ary) { print reverse; }`, with list context imposed on it by `print`, it has no arguments and thus prints nothing.

Answer (score -1):

In scalar context, `reverse` reverses the characters of a string.

```
my $s = "abc";
$s = reverse($s);
say $s;
# cba
```

In list context, `reverse` reverses the scalars of its argument list.

```
my @a = qw( abc def ghi );
@a = reverse(@a);
say "@a";
# ghi def abc
```

Clearly, both uses are very consistent with each other. The only possible lack of consistency between scalar-context `reverse` and list-context `reverse` is what happens when you provide no argument expression. Scalar-context `reverse` defaults to using `$_`, but doing so would make no sense for list-context `reverse`, so it doesn't treat that case specially.

That means the reason `print reverse for "word";` prints nothing is that the reverse of zero items is zero items.

Comment: Mention that in scalar context only, it defaults to $_

Comment: @ysth, done. . .